# Can't detect empty result

Tags: php

Depending on whether any results are found or not I want to set a value to `$case_num` and store it in an array to pass back to an `AJAX` call using `json`.  The code I am using works as expected if an entry is found but if there are no results the value passed back is simply null.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cases WHERE name LIKE '%$serial%' 
        AND DATE(date_entered) = CURDATE()";

$result_case = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_case);

 if(!empty($result_case)){
      $case_id = $row['id'];
      $case_num = $row['name'];
    }else{
      $case_num = 'not found';
 }

$output_array = array(
    'source' => $source,
    'case_found' => $case_num
);

echo json_encode($output_array);
```

Comment: What do you want $case_num to be if there are no results?

Comment: `$result_case` will never be empty, __NEVER__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `if` condition

```
if($row)
```

Remember that `mysqli_fetch_array` will return `NULL` if there's no rows to fetch and `mysqli_query` returns a boolean based on if the query succeeded (as in generated no errors)

Answer (score 1):

$result_case arent null, if no have result, the value is false, you can try use like (isset($row)) or $result_case!=false

Comment: `$row` will be set regardless. So `isset($row)` is a useless test